# Using IXmlSerialization, how can I serialize a T property?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

My question is so simple.

Imagine we have a Foo class. and has a T property.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Property { get; set; }
}
```

I want to implement in it IXmlSerializable and my problem is I have no idea to imitate the standard XmlSerialization. I really have no idea about how to write this property like the standart XmlSerlalization.

UPDATE: I did this and it's not working

```
public class Foo<T> : IFoo
    where T : IXmlSerializable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooA : Foo<string> { }
public class FooB : Foo<int> { }
public class FooC : Foo<List<Double>> { }
```

When I serialized this classes (A, B and C). I wanna have something like this:

Using first class:

```
<FooA>
    <Value>StringDemo</Value>
</FooA>
```

Using second class:

```
<FooB>
    <Value>2</Value>
</FooB>
```

Using third class:

```
<FooC>
    <Value>
        <ArrayOfDouble xsi:..>
            <Double>3.1416</Double>
            <Double>4.2</Double>
        </ArrayOfDouble>
    </Value>
</FooC>
```

Something like this is what I wanted, I don't want to implement in all of this a custom XmlSerializer, I mean the default which the standard serialization use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) in `Foo<T>`, and T (using `where T : IXmlSerializable`. The implementation in `Foo<T>` would then be responsible for writing a wrapper element with type information (in [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.writexml.aspx)) and call `WriteXml` on T, and recreate the instance from the type information (in [ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.readxml.aspx)) and call `ReadXml` on T.

Basic types like `String` and `Double` is not `IXmlSerializable`, so you cant have `where T : IXmlSerializable` if you want to support them. You can also provide default implementations of `ReadXml` and `WriteXml`. This works since you need to create a `Foo<T>` before calling `ReadXml`, forcing you to know `T`.

```
public class Foo<T> : IXmlSerializable {
    public T Value { get; set; }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() {
        return GetSchema();
    }

    protected virtual XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        return null;
    }

    public virtual void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        Value = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public virtual void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, Value);
    }
}
```